# How to enqueue a periodic task if it gets terminated in celery?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

Let's say there is a periodic task scheduled to run every hour. A worker receives the tasks and starts processing. While the task is being processed, the celeryd process (controlled via supervisord) gets restarted (supervisorctl restart all). Even though the task had never finished execution, it won't get re-executed.

How can I re-queue the periodic task right away and prevent the multiple versions of the tasks run at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a nicer way to do it, but you *could* just use the periodic task to create a regular task in the queue (e.g., `my_actual_task.defer(…)`) which will not be removed from the queue until it is completed (assuming you are using acks_late).

If you're not using acks_late, you can put the bulk of the task in a try, and in the corresponding `finally` put a [`my_actual_task.retry()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry).

Either way, you should generally avoid killing workers without giving them a chance to finish up what they're doing.